# How to set the version number to have a different starting point in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use the version number plugin to format the version number of my Jenkins pipeline.

```
BUILD_NUMBER = VersionNumber (projectStartDate: '2021-08-01', versionNumberString: '${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}', versionPrefix: '', worstResultForIncrement: 'SUCCESS')
```

I want to start the build number from a particular number though, say 10, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

https://{your_jenkins_domain}/script (jenkins -> manage jenkins -> script console)

run script
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("JobFullName/BranchName").updateNextBuildNumber(NextBuildNumber)

For example:
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("testjob/Release1.9").updateNextBuildNumber(115)

then run build